# Can King Kong survive a nuclear blast?

Tags: monsterverse, king-kong

In *Godzilla vs Kong* (2021,) we see Godzilla repeatedly attacking Kong with his atomic breath, and Kong mostly either deflects it through his axe or gets hit but survives.

Can King Kong survive an atomic blast? After all, he was able to survive Godzilla's atomic breath.

Comment: If I remember correctly, that monster Godzilla was fighting in Godzilla (2014) - which Wikipedia is calling a MUTO - was also feeding on nuclear radiation and stole the nuke they had brought at the end for its nest or something. Unless I misunderstood the plot entirely.

Comment: I did not see the movie, but are Kong and King Kong the same thing? I guess that some clarification might be needed. King Kong is the name of the original character - simply an organic huge being, while Kong is something else - even if they are related, being in the same francize.

Comment: If these titans could be killed with a nuke, they'd have killed them with a nuke.